# Windows Server 2008 and eSata External Connection

Tags: windows-server-2008, esata

Can anyone recommend a good eSATA PCIe card for Windows Server 2008 (x64)? I bought a J-Micron JMB363 and it's recognized by the OS and I can install one of their reference drivers, but it's not picking up the drive I have attached to it.

Basically, I want to be able to transfer exported Hyper-V machines quickly to an external drive, and it seems that using one of these eSATA cards is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Adaptec RAID 1225SA](http://www.adaptec.com/en-US/products/Controllers/Hardware/sata/entry/AAR-1225SA/) is great, highly recommend it for W2K8.

Comment: Sweet, that one looks pretty good; I think I should have checked for Server 2008 drivers before I just bought the cheapest one. Stupid of me really.

Answer (score 1):

I've had some compatibility issues with eSATA drives - had a few where the drive was fine when internally connected but just wouldn't work over eSATA. The drives in question were the first Seagate Free Agent external units to come with eSATA interfaces so this may just have been a technology maturity thing but it's worth checking that the external drive you are trying to use doesn't have any known issues.

Answer (score 0):

We've used an LSI Logic MegaRAID 8704ELP with an eSATA daughter backplate (so you need two slots free the server) connected to a four JBOD enclosure as our Backup Exec backup-to-disk folder. Has worked very well.

Cheers, Rob.